# how to change entry point function of GNU C++ program?

Tags: gcc, g++

how to change entry point function of GNU c++ program?

I am able to change the entry point of a GCC C program.  But using the same compile options for C++ gives me an error: cannot find entry symbol.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test(int argc, char *argv[]) ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("HELLO main\n" );
  printf("PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT\n");

  return (0);
}

int test(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int val;
  printf("HELLO test()\n");
  val = main(argc, argv);
  exit(val) ;
}
```

I can compile and run using gcc:

```
gcc -etest  entry.c -o entry
```

but compiling with g++ does not work:

```
$ g++ -etest  entry.c -o entry
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol test; defaulting to 0000000000000610
```

Comment: Maybe you need to declare the `test()` function with `extern "C"` to avoid the C++ name mangling.

Comment: that did it.  thank you.

extern "C" int test(int argc, char *argv[]) ;

Comment: Great, I will add it as answer for the records.

Comment: What is your bigger problem you are trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `test()` function must be declared with `extern "C"` to avoid the C++ name mangling:

```
extern "C" int test(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: You can also pass the mangled name as entry point (possibly _Z4testiPPc, use `nm` to find out).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the entry point of a C++ program is symbol `_start`. This function sets up C and C++ standard libraries, calls constructors of global objects and eventually calls `main`. By changing the entry point you bypass that initialization, so that `printf` may not work because `stdout` has not been initialized.

Comment: how to get _start to call a function other than main?

Comment: @StephenRichter `_start` always calls `main`, so an easy option would be for `main` to call `a_function_other_than_main`.